# Можно ли загружать страницы в коде без объявления в XAMl?

Tags: c#, wpf, веб-программирование, webbrowser

Можно ли загружать страницы в коде без объявления в XAMl?

Код ниже не работает. Событие никогда не наступит.

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.google.ru/"));
browser.LoadCompleted += brows_DocumentCompleted;
```

Если объявить WebBrowser в XAMl и использовать в коде, все работает.
Событие происходит.

```
browserXaml.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.google.ru/"));
browserXaml.LoadCompleted += brows_DocumentCompleted;
```

Comment: Возможно, вам следует разбить это сообщение на два отдельных вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо. Отредактировал.

Comment: Окей, а делаете ли вы ещё что-то с переменной `browser` в первом случае?

Comment: Может стоит использовать с таком случае не визуальный компонент, а какой-нибудь специальный класс на типа WebClient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите загрузить файл без визуальных компонент, не используйте их.

Для этого есть специальные классы `WebClient` (более старый) и `HttpClient` (более новый).

Пример использования:

```
string s;
using (var cl = new WebClient())
   s = cl.DownloadString("https://www.google.ru/");
```

или лучше асинхронный вариант:

```
string s;
using (var cl = new WebClient())
   s = await cl.DownloadStringAsync("https://www.google.ru/");
```

(Вы также можете [загрузить в массив байт или файл](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).)

То же для `HttpClient`:

```
string s;
using (var cl = new HttpClient())
   s = await cl.GetStringAsync("https://www.google.ru/");
```

(`HttpClient`, кажется, поддерживает лишь асинхронные операции.)

Если вы хотите читать поток по мере прихода ответа, вы можете воспользоваться `GetStreamAsync`:

```
using (var cl = new HttpClient())
using (var stream = await cl.GetStreamAsync("https://www.google.ru/"))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Влад, здравствуйте! Хотел дописать свой вопрос в виде коментария к вашему ответу здесть, поскольку тематика очень близка, но потом понял, что проще создать новый вопрос. Вы не могли бы посмотреть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/773014/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-loadcompleted-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-webbrowser-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko: боюсь, вопросы на самом деле сильно отличаются. У меня в ответе про компоненту для скачивания файлов, она намного проще. `WebBrowser` -- компонента для разбора и отображения HTML, с ней всё сложнее.