# Как получить событие LoadCompleted контрола WebBrowser, не вставляя данный контрол в XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser

У меня нет потребности использовать WebBrowser в XAML, мне он нужен всего лишь для того что бы иметь возможность вызвать событие Click на одном из тегов загруженной HTML страницы.

Я не могу вызывать событие Click на нужном мне теге, до того как загрузиться страница. Для того что бы получить уведомление о загрузке страницы мне нужно подписаться на событие LoadCompleted. Но, судя из того что я вижу событие LoadCompleted не генерируется пока WebBrowser не будет добавлен в XAML.

По причине того что я хочу осуществлять загрузку множества HTML страниц параллельно, перспектива постоянно добавлять WebBrowser контрол в разметку XAML до загрузки одной из множества страниц и удаление его из этой разметки после загрузки нужной страницы выглядит не очень удобно.

Моя цель получить доступ к вызову события Click на загруженной HTML странице без возни с ХАМL.

Можно ли получить доступ к событию LoadCompleted контрола  WebBrowser без его привязки к XAML. Возможно ли это? Может быть есть какой то другой путь?

Код отражающий суть проблемы (WebBrowser в XAML не добавлялся)

```
public partial class SettingsWindow : Window
{
    private WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();

    public SettingsWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.browser.LoadCompleted += Browser_LoadCompleted;
        this.browser.Source         = new Uri(@"https://www.google.com.ua/");
        //this.browser.Navigate(path); <-- пробовал загружать страницу и этим способом.
    }

    private void Browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Этот обработчик никогда не вызывается если объект WebBrowser не 
        // добавлен в XAML или не добавлен программным путем в качестве 
        // дочернего компонента к одному из существующих контролов окна.
    }        
}
```

Comment: "Но, судя из того что я вижу событие LoadCompleted не генерируется пока WebBrowser не будет добавлен в XAML." Можно узнать на чем основан такой вывод?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Если я просто создаю объект WebBrowser не добавляя его в XAML, подписываясь на событие LoadCompleted   и вызывая загрузку страницы при помощи метода Navigate(). Событие LoadCompleted не генерируется - никогда. Если создать объект в разметке XAML, присоединив к упомянутому событию обработчик, все работает.

Comment: интересно, можете написать MCVE?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Если я правильно понял, сокращение MCVE означает - самодостаточный пример кода? Добавил, максимально упрощенный вариант. Описанная мной проблема в нем присутствует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно, событие `LoadCompleted` для WPF WebBrowser не вызывается до тех пор, пока он не добавлен в какое-либо отображаемое окно или элемент управления, это известная проблема. Причина ее в том, как WebBrowser осуществляет инициализацию своего внутреннего ActiveX-элемента Internet Explorer, который и занимается загрузкой страницы. Это можно понять, посмотрев в его исходный код на Reference Source.

Для корректной работы события `DocumentCompleted` внутреннего ActiveX-объекта класс `ActiveXHost` должен быть переведен в состояние `ActiveXState.InPlaceActive`. По умолчанию он находится в `ActiveXState.Running` (см. [инициализацию свойства](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/WebBrowser.cs,fc4291456c615b4c)), переход в состояние InPlaceActive происходит при вызове метода [BuildWindowCore](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Interop/ActiveXHost.cs,d9d828289509b434,references), который вызывается только при отображении родительского окна элемента. *Это поведение отличается от аналогичного элемента в WinForms, который сразу переводится в InPlaceActive при инициализации, см. [здесь](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WebBrowser.cs,b0a9d3ff01a86d4e))*.

**Решение 1 - Использование WinForms WebBrowser**

Элемент [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) в WinForms избавлен от этой проблемы (аналогичное событие `DocumentCompleted` всегда вызывается), и функционально ни в чем не уступает элементу из WPF. Можно просто добавить ссылку на System.Windows.Forms и использовать его.

**Решение 2 - Использование окна за пределами экрана**

Для вызова `BuildWindowCore` требуется видимое окно, однако никто не запрещает сделать координаты отрицательными и поместить окно за пределы экрана:

```
Window wnd = new Window();
wnd.Content = browser;
wnd.ShowInTaskbar = false;
wnd.Top = -1000;
wnd.Left = -1000;
wnd.Width = 0;
wnd.Height = 0;
wnd.Show();
```

**Решение 3 - Грязный хак с использованием отражения**

Просто вызвать внутренний метод `TransitionUpTo`, передав в качества аргумента константу InPlaceActive (4):

```
using System.Reflection;
const int InPlaceActive = 4;

//...

var method = browser.GetType().GetMethod("TransitionUpTo",BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
method.Invoke(browser, new object[] {InPlaceActive});
```

Comment: Решение номер три, не выглядит таким уж и грязным) ведь работа браузера от этого никак не страдает и сам способ в последствии судя по всему не вызывает никаких побочных эффектов и не требует какого либо особого обращения с контролом. Спасибо за предоставленные решения!

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko, рефлексия плоха тем, что приватные члены могут измениться хоть в минорном обновлении фреймворка. Если ваше приложение работает нормально в .NET 4.5, то оно может внезапно перестать работать на .NET 4.5.1, например.